# Programmatically clean windows 8 search charm suggestions

Tags: c#, search, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am creating a metro style app and I've implemented the search contract with suggestions. When a suggestion is picked, it remains stored for other searches even if it doesn't exist anymore(like a web text field cache). How can I erase these suggestions?

(**EDIT:** and if it isn't possible to clean it programmatically how can I erase that suggestions manually, because they filled all the space in the search-box suggestion area.)

[image: Search Suggestions]

As you can see even if I don't search for anything the suggestions are there.

Comment: I am going to guess its not possible to modify a user's search suggestions because it might contain some other data the user wants, I suggest you research how a search contract works.  You might have to use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out: `Settings Charm > Change PC Settings (Windows 8 metro style control panel)) > Search > Erase History` (i am not sure that is is the proper naming in english for the path i have windows in another language).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  The intent of the Search Charm is to remain open so the user can select multiple applications until he or she gets the desired results.

Comment: I don't want to close the charm. What I want is: I've created an app and added Search contract with suggestions. When you type something to search in my app the app search for matches and give you suggestion under the search text field. When you select one of that suggestions it remain stored and when you write again one or two letter that match the previous clicked suggestion it pops up even if it doesn't exist as a suggestion of my app (like a captcha on a website that stores all the codes that you've entered)

Comment: UPDATED question. Added photo.